# The value of Noda Time library: Test Scenarios

Tags: portal, .net-7.0, nodatime

I have gone through the effort of including Noda Time in my portal to calculate my times.  However, I am having a hard time demonstrating that it was worth the effort.  Can someone please give me a couple of test scenarios that show where there is greater accuracy in using this library instead of just keeping the offset value?

So, rephrasing the original question.  What scenarios could happen in the next 10 years that would cause my date calculation using just offset to become inaccurate?

Note:  My system doesn't look back.  It is a patient scheduling system that looks forward.  But, yes.  In 10 years we'll have some data to look back on and time zone weirdness can occur in the next 10 years.

Comment: We don't know what your system does, so it's very hard to say much. But if you're working out a UTC offset *now* for a future date, then that can clearly become incorrect if the rules change between now and that future date - e.g. if the time zone in question abandons daylight saving time changes. You don't really *need* Noda Time to work with time zone IDs instead of assuming that predictions about future UTC offsets will be correct... it just makes it easier (in my biased opinion, as the primary author).

Comment: (It's also unclear how the portal tag is relevant here.)

Comment: Ping for improvements to this question (or deletion).

Comment: I believe my learning investment will pay off in the future with upcoming requirements. But, I thought there would be a more obvious upfront benefit. I was hoping to provide my testers with a few scenarios that demonstrates said benefit.

Comment: Again though, the benefit you're talking about is "using a time zone ID instead of a UTC offset". That's entirely separate from the benefits of using Noda Time. Obviously I believe there are benefits in using Noda Time, but that's not really what you're talking about.

Comment: The portal tag is on there because I have a web portal that will be used around the world.  I give the user 3 options to display their dates in UTC, Local and Origin (Time it was in the Time Zone from which it Originated).

Comment: The question really isn't specific to web portals though - I doubt it's really useful. Fundamentally this is a matter of "there are multiple time zones involved". And again, what you've actually asked about isn't specific to Noda Time either - or even .NET. You're basically asking under what scenarios keeping the time zone ID is better than keeping the UTC offset - that's completely technology-neutral. (And the answer is "when time zone rules change" as per my first comment...)